# Probability - Interview Question

Tags: probability

Hi I recently got this question in an interview and would like help solving it.

There were 2 boys and 3 girls in a room. A new baby entered the
room whose gender was unknown (but equally likely to be a boy/girl).
A nurse came into the room and picked one baby randomly and it
turned out to be a boy. What’s the probability that the new baby was
a boy?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Did you try using Bayes' theorem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Questions that just contain the statement of a problem without contain the author's own thoughts/work are very unpopular here and tend to get closed for lack of context. So please edit the question to include that.

Comment: I think it is noteworthy that you have now three different answers with three different results :)

Comment: State of mathematics education... And as the world evolves and loses its ability to reality check itself, we now relegate ourselves to finding answers by popular voting...

Comment: Sounds more to me like the interviewers wanted to test how attentive the interviewee was to slight differences (and possibly how open to thinking out-of-the-box). It seems to me that the original boys and girls were not necessarily babies.

Answer (score 3):

Let $bg$ denote the event that the new child is a boy, and the randomly chosen child is then a girl. Label other events similarly viz. $P(bb)=P(bg)=\frac{1}{4},\,P(gb)=\frac{1}{6},\,P(gg)=\frac{1}{3}$. Then $$P(\text{new boy}|\text{boy chosen})=\frac{P(bb)}{P(bb)+P(gb)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{3}{5},$$where to simplify I've multiplied numerator and denominator by $12$.

As an existing answer that reached this value has been downvoted, I double-checked my answer with the Python [here](https://repl.it/repls/RadiantLinedAmpersand). In one run, the conditional probability estimate was $0.602380952381$, which is close enough to $0.6$ for the purposes of a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

I won't spoil the answer for you, but think of what happens(intuitively) in extreme cases:

Suppose there were 1000 girls in that room and 1 boy. The nurse goes in and picks up a boy. What's the probability that the newborn was a boy?

Suppose there were 1000 boys and 1 girl. The nurse goes in and picks up a boy. What's the probability the newborn was a boy?

Use conditional probability to formalize your intuition.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\boxed{3/5}$

Bayes' Rule asserts that the conditional probability of event $A$ happening given that event $B$ occurred is given by

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B \mid A) \cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$$

Here, your event $A$ is the event that the new child is a boy. Your event $B$ is the event of selecting one child and it being a boy.

$P(A) = 1/2$ as you mentioned.

To compute $P(B)$, note that there's a $1/2$ chance of having a boy. Moreover, if the new child is a boy, the probability of choosing a boy becomes $1/2$. Now, the probability that both of these events occur is given by

$$1/2 \cdot 1/2 = 1/4.$$

Now, consider the case where the child is a girl. This happens again with probability one half, and if it is a girl the probability of choosing a boy becomes $2/6$. Putting these together, we get

$$1/2 \cdot 2/6= 1/6.$$

So, $P(B) = 1/4 + 1/6= 5/12$.

Finally, $P(B \mid A)$ is the chance of choosing a boy given that the newborn is a boy, which occurs with probability $1/2$. Plugging these into our equation provided by Bayes' Rule, we get $P(A \mid B) = 3/5.$

Comment: P(A) = 1/2 right? but how do i figure out P(B)?

Comment: You are correct about $P(A)$. You can compute $P(B)$ by considering the two cases (case one: the new child is a boy, and case two: the new child is a girl).

Comment: Im sorry do you mind explaining a little further? thanks

Comment: Sure. Check my edit.

Comment: Thanks. since the events are conditional P(A∩B) wouldnt be as simple as P(A) * P(B).. in order to find out P(A|B) how would u compute the intersection.

Comment: Yes, you are right that it isn't that simple. Use the equality $P(A\cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B \mid A)$. Now, $P(B \mid A) $ is just the chance of a boy given the newborn is a boy, which is $1/2$. We already computed $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. Plug them in and you're done. Your answer should be $1/2$.

Comment: "and if it is a girl the probability of choosing a boy becomes 2/4." And if you change $2/4$ to $2/6$, your answer would be fine. Note that the total number after a baby joined the group of 5 babies became $6$.

Comment: @farruhota check again

Comment: +1. It is good now.

Answer (score 0):

$p(new\ baby=boy|picked\ baby=boy)=\frac{p(new\ baby=boy\ and \ picked\ baby=boy)}{p(picked\ baby=boy | new\ baby=boy)p(new\ baby=boy)+p(picked\ baby=boy | new\ baby=girl)p(new\ baby=girl)}$
$p(new\ baby=boy|picked\ baby=boy)=\frac{1/2x1/2}{1/2x1/2+1/3x1/2}=3/5$

Comment: Interestingly, if you had a room of, say, a million boys and no girls, the odds that the new baby is a boy is capped at 0.5!  On the other hand, if you had a million girls and no boys, the odds that the new baby is a boy is 1, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Note that first a new baby entered the room (there became $6$ babies in total) and then the nurse randomly picked up a boy from among them. Hence:
$$P(B_1)=\frac12; P(G_1)=\frac12;\\
P(B_2|B_1)=\frac36; P(G_2|B_1)=\frac36; P(B_2|G_1)=\frac26; P(G_2|G_1)=\frac46.$$
Now you want to find (using [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)):
$$P(B_1|B_2)=\frac{P(B_1\cap B_2)}{P(B_2)}=\frac{P(B_1)\cdot P(B_2|B_1)}{P(B_1)\cdot P(B_2|B_1)+P(G_1)\cdot P(B_2|G_1)}=\\
\frac{\frac12\cdot \frac12}{\frac12\cdot \frac12+\frac12\cdot \frac26}=\frac3{5}.$$

Answer (score -1):

I would like someone to verify this, since my confidence isn't high.
This is a method that helps corroborate chances. If something doesn't quite add up, you'd generally notice, since then one or more of the equations would be wrong.

[cube chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RguuE.png)

The description explains several events with 4 conditions; the chance a boy or a girl is added, and the chance the nurse picks a boy or a girl.

What you're asking is basically, what are the odds something happens, given that we know that thing already happened. In this case it's "What are the odds a boy was added, given that we know the nurse picked a boy". You can see the events cross together with the answer being $1/4$

Answer (score -1):

Let:

A - chosen child is a boy

N - new child is a boy

You are asked $P(N|A)$

Which is by using the bayes theorem:

$$P(N|A) = \frac{P(A|N)P(N)}{P(A)} = \frac{3/6 * 1/2}{1/2*3/6 + 1/2*2/6} = 0.6$$

We know $P(A|N)$ = 3/6 because if the new child is a boy we would have 6 childs and 3 boys, we can do the same for $P(A|!N) = 2/6$

We can calculate $P(A)$ as $P(N)P(A|N) + P(!N)P(A|!N)$ basically the probability that A happens if N happens or !N happens.